# Use webservice from to project in same SharePoint 2013 solution

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint

Is it possible to use web service from to difference project in the same SharePoint 2013 solution?

I have a solution with 'a main' project with web services, it works fine. I have add a new project with web service. The web service does not work in the new project.

This works fine: domain.com/_layouts/15/MainProject/webserviceOne.asmx

This does not work: domain.com/_layouts/15/NewProject/webserviceTwo.asmx

If I move the webserviceTwo to the Main project (and change the code, sow it match the main project) it works.

Is it only possible have web service from to project, to point at ‘/Layouts/15/’ ?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution here https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2015/05/22/SharePoint-Application-Pages-Visual-Studio.aspx?Page=1

The only thind I need to do, was: right-clicking project and following the path Add | SharePoint Mapped folder.

Comment: It can also be find here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vssharepointtoolsblog/2010/03/12/deploying-files-using-mapped-folders/